# How exactly could you prove the following question about quantum computing?

Tags: algorithm, quantization

[image]

Consider a function f mapping a bit onto another bit, i.e. f:{0,1}---> {0,1}. The function f is either constant, so f(0)= f(1) or balanced, so f(0)different f(1). Thq qunatum gate for the Deutsch algorithm id given in Figure 1. The second gate f has the following form:

Comment: You might be better off at Physics, or Computing. I'm not sure quantum computing has really made it to Engineering yet.

Comment: Or https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com. You should also explain what you already understand and what you've done so far as an attempted solution.